# Twitter API 1.1 + Loading Public tweets in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

Good day,

Now that we cant use the single liner REST call to retrieve json of any public timeline from twitter, can anyone please guide me towards a simple tutorial on how to display public tweets of any timeline in a UITableView?

Thanks
Waris

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dummycode/social-media/blob/master/Social%20Media/TwitterViewController.m)